# Approaches to teaching and learning analysis

Tags: analysis, soft-question, self-learning

I found that studying linear algebra by getting into vector spaces and linear transformations first made things very easy. This is the approach Halmos or Axler, just to name a few, take.

IMHO, the alternative of going through solving systems of linear equations beforehand, obscures the topic.

What would be equivalent, slightly abstract approaches to study analysis for a freshman? A bit of topology and metric spaces, like Rudin? Multivariate calculus with differential forms, like Hubbard & Hubbard?

Answer (score 1):

On the first two paragraphs of your question, I think that you are right: **linear algebra** first may give you one more tool to face and understand further topics in calculus/analysis.

On the other hand, another keyword you used is **Topology**: I think this latter, more than others, can give you a more *general* point of view than watching things "in $\mathbb{R}$" or "in $\mathbb{C}$".

For example, in italian degree courses in engineering we have plenty of "pure" maths subject (which is good) but not much topology (that I only studied later in BSc Maths, which is bad I think). I would add such subject to BEng courses, because I mentioned and heard about "open intervals" for years, ignoring the more general notion of **open set** (and this is not optimizing, in my "student's" point of view).

To make it as clear as I can, thinking of it years later, I would have preferred some more notions and background in *general* topology, before solving exercises about *Euclidean* topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly topology and metric spaces make a nice abstract (but not *too* abstract) intro to some of the fundamental concepts of analysis, basically continuity. But that's only one part of analysis.

Simmons *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* is a classic that, starting with metric spaces, will take you all the way to the Gelfand-Naimark theorem on Banach algebras, one of the pinnacles of 20th century analysis. Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is a slim volume that remains one of the best first encounters with differential forms and Stoke's theorem (that is, to someone inclined to abstraction, at the freshman level). I happen to like Lang's *Analysis*.

Comment: *Calculus on manifolds is a slim volume that remains one of the best first encounters with differential forms and Stokes's theorem* [citation needed]. Otherwise, I agree with your answer.

Comment: Not sure about your point: what else is needed for the citation? Or do you not like Spivak's book?

Comment: It was mostly a joke wiki-style, but it was intended to show that I dislike (strongly) this Spivak's book.

Comment: Also, I meant in the context of the OP's question, i.e., a preference for abstraction at the freshman level.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the chat room before. I'd be more than happy to discuss in the chat. (I just don't know how to create a room and now you've left)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to talk in the chat, but I will follow the conversation, as this topic is of utmost interest to me. I'm self-studying, so this kind of choices matter.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I'm in the chat.